# How can you pass the HashTable as a parameter to the function and export the data into the csv?

Tags: function, powershell, module, hashtable

I have build the PowerShell module function which captures the data such as:

- Start Date
- Start Time
- Server Name
- User (who executes the script
- Technology
- Script Name
- Script Path
- Execution Time (# of seconds took the script from start to end)
- Error Message (if there is any error message in the script)

The above points provides data for each of the script, I have enabled the module and calling out the function in each of my script. However, there are some scripts which provides build data and some scripts which don't. For example, there is one script which enables **MS Project** and **MS Visio** license to the end users and it gives me the data on **# of Project** license assigned and **# of Visio** license assigned.

I am trying to find the way on how to capture the build data from some of my scripts. I want to capture the data with **headers** and merge them with my **HashTable** which is in my module script. Altogether, I want to export the data to the **csv** file.

I am trying to understand what I am missing? I used **param** method but couldn't output any data.

Here is my PowerShell module code

```
function Get-Info(){

$date = (Get-Date -f  "MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm")

#TimeStamp
$reportDate = (Get-Date -f  "MM/dd/yyyy")

$reportTime = (Get-Date -f  "hh:mm:ss tt")

#Server
$serverName = $env:COMPUTERNAME 

#user
$user = $env:UserName

#script name
$scriptName = split-path $MyInvocation.PSCommandPath -Leaf

#script path
$scriptPath = split-path $MyInvocation.PSCommandPath 

#service account
$serviceAccount = $tenantAdmin

#measure execution time (start to finish)
[timespan]$executionTime = Measure-Command {0..10000 | ForEach-Object {$i++} }

$runTime = $executionTime.Milliseconds

#Technology Type
$technology = Split-Path (Split-Path $scriptPath -Parent) -Leaf

#error handling

If($errorMessage -eq $null){

    $errorMessage = "None"
}

if ($errorMessage -ne $null){

    $errorMessage = $ErrorMessage

}

$fileName = $scriptName.Trim(".ps1")

$Hashtable = @()
$Hashtable += New-Object psobject  -Property @{

"Script Name" = $scriptName;
"Execution Date" = $reportDate;
"Execution Time" = $reportTime;
"Service Account" = $serviceAccount;
"User" = $user;
"Server Name" = $serverName;
"Script Path" = $scriptPath;
"RunTimeMS" = $runTime;
"Error Message" = $errorMessage;
"Technology" = $technology;

}

if($myHashTable -eq $null){

$Hashtable | Export-Csv "D:\MyFileName\$fileName$date.csv" -NoTypeInformation


}

if($myHashTable -ne $null){

$finalTable = $Hashtable + $myHashTable

$finalTable | Export-Csv "D:\MyFileName\$fileName$date.csv" -NoTypeInformation


}
```

Comment: Thats not a true hasthable btw, youre converting it into a `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`

Comment: I'm gonna give you a hint on how to merge 2 or more objects. First you get the count of items of the largest object. Then you get the property members of both objects. Then you merge them into one single object using a for loop and inside that loop you loop over the properties on each position of the objects you want merge.

Comment: @santisq I am not sure if I understand you correctly. The hashtable above gets the data from the function from the powershell script, and what I am trying to do is to pass another hashtable as a parameter to the function from the script.